# Is it okay to call clearInterval() before setInterval()?

Tags: javascript

I have a following fragment of code:

```
if (someCondition) {
    // clear globTimer first??
    globTimer = setInterval(function() {
        someBlinkingCode;
    }, 1000);
} else {
    clearInterval(globTimer);
}
```

but this part of code can be called multiple times where `someCondition` will be true. It means multiple intervals will be created and not all of them will be destroyed. And after a certain time blinking was more frequent than 1 sec so I added `clearInterval(globTimer);` instead of the comment. This change solved my problem but is this solution okay? Is it okay to call `clearInterval()` more times for the same variable or call it for `undefined`?

Comment: The code seems alright to me...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it's fine to call `clearInterval` (and `clearTimeout`) with "invalid" identifiers.  [The specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/timers.html#dom-windowtimers-clearinterval) says:

> The clearInterval() method must clear the entry identified as handle from the list of active intervals of the WindowTimers object on which the method was invoked, where handle is the argument passed to the method, if any. (**If handle does not identify an entry in the list of active intervals of the WindowTimers object on which the method was invoked, the method does nothing.**)

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: so anytime I want to use a `setInterval()/setTimeout()` it is a good strategy to call `clearInterval()/clearTimeout()` first? It will harm nothing, if I understood it right.....

Comment: @user3719454 If it's an interval/timer that you might invoke multiple times and you want to be sure you only have 1 at a time, yes - it can be a good strategy.